# flutter --dart-define-from-file is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-define

I want to import env value from json file to my project but get this error.

```
Json config define file "--dart-define-from-file=config.json" is not a file, please fix first!
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX20D.png)
My project literally have 2 files which is main.dart and config.json as you see in the image.
I tried to replce the additional run args with

```
--dart-define-from-file config.json
```

or

```
--dart-define-from-file="config.json"
```

but none of that seems to be working.

I also tried to type it manually on terminal but got the same result.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yOZM.png)

What went wrong here?

Comment: Can you add the file structure of your project?

Comment: @spydon It just fresh new flutter project with the config.json file. You can see it i  the first picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either move the `config.json` file to the root of your project, or set:

```bash
--dart-define-from-file="lib/config.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has been silently removed in Flutter 3.16. There's a [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138793) talking about it